# Настройка разных айпи под разные скрипты

Tags: ubuntu, веб-сервер

Нужно настроить сервер так, чтобы разные экземпляры скрипта из разных папок работали на разных, выделенных им, айпи, причём без использования прокси и впн, а при помощи предоставляемых сервером адресов (их можно сделать несколько для одного сервера).

Сервер на Ubuntu 18.04
Скрипты - боты, работают на питоне

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: На севрвере достаточно поднять эти ip что бы они в принципе работали. А дальше уже в питоновском скрипте указать явно с какого ip ему работать. Например при использовании requests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773033/python-requests-how-to-bind-to-different-source-ip-for-each-request